# React Native iOS Build is failing with expo

Tags: ios, react-native

I am getting below error while running the below command to generate the iOS build:

```
eas build --platform ios
```

**Error:**

iOS build failed:
Some pods require a higher minimum deployment target.
You can use the expo-build-properties config plugin (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/) to override the default native build properties and set a different minimum deployment target.

I have already add required settings in my app.json file, below is my app.json file code:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "*****",
    "slug": "*****",
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
      "url": "*****"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": false,
      "bundleIdentifier": "*****",
      "deploymentTarget": "13.0",
      "buildNumber": "1.1.0"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "*****",
      "versionCode": 2,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "minimumOSVersion": "12.0"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "*****"
      }
    },
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "sdkVersion"
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know where am I wrong ?

Comment: In plugins you have "minimumOSVersion": "12.0" can you with "minimumOSVersion": "13.0" since for iOS your "deploymentTarget": "13.0" ?

Comment: Issue resolved now.

Comment: Please mention how you solved?

Comment: @NeeteshKeshari how were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm getting a `Correlation ID` error anytime I add `expo-build-properties` to the config, so I'm curious also how you solved it.